# JavaScript setting element's background color fails randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my JavaScript pageLoad() function, I create a div element that acts as a button, and append it to the parent using appendChild(). When clicked on, it fires a function that adds an element above the button using insertBefore(element, parent.lastChild) within an AJAX success callback. This works great 90% of the time, but on some random occasions, the background color of the button doesn't get set after a click, and it ends up becoming transparent (see pictures). However, it can still be clicked on. Anyone know why this might be happening? Bug occurs on Chrome and Firefox.

Bug: [image] Intended: [image]

button creation in pageLoad():

```
let addJobButton = document.createElement("div");
addJobButton.setAttribute("class", "addJobButton"); // CSS that sets background-color
let plusIcon = document.createElement("span");
plusIcon.setAttribute("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-plus");
addJobButton.appendChild(plusIcon);
addJobButton.setAttribute("onClick", "addJobBox(event)");
boxList[i].appendChild(addJobButton);
```

addJobBox(event) function:

```
let tempDayBox = event.target.parentElement;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Schedule.aspx/InsertItem',
    data: JSON.stringify({ Content: "", CrewID: tempDayBoxCrewID, Week: tempDayBoxWeek, Year: tempDayBoxYear, Day: tempDayBoxDay, IsLocked: "N" }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {

        let jobBox = document.createElement("div");
        jobBox.className = "day-board-list";
        document.getElementById(tempDayBox.id).insertBefore(jobBox, tempDayBox.lastChild);
        bindMenu();
        console.log("Job '" + jobBox.id + "' added successfully.");
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

CSS being set:

```
.addJobButton {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: The only thing I see that could potentially be different "sometimes" is `let tempDayBox = event.target.parentElement;` where the event target can be a child element instead of the element having the event handler. So since you then insert before that... It can do strange things. I suggest you console log it and try to recreate the issue. If I'm right, the solution would be something like `let tempDayBox = event.target.closest(".someSelectorForTheRightElement");`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I believe you're correct! I have found that the issue only occurs when I click on the glyphicon span inside of the button instead of the button itself. Then it thinks the button is the parent instead of the element list. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let tempDayBox = event.target.parentElement;` may not always be the expected element. It can be a child of the element having the event handler.

Since you `insertBefore` that element, better be sure it is the right one. I suggest using:

`let tempDayBox = event.target.closest("someSelectorForTheRightElement");`

Comment: This worked! The new element was being wrongfully inserted inside of the button, giving the allusion that the background color was transparent. When in reality the plus glyphicon was just extending beyond the button's height.